# Is it common to teach kids about the jumping letters?

Tags: phonics

When I was a kid I remember distinctly this lesson on how to pronounce a word. If there is only one consonant between two vowels like in the word "make" then the *e* jumps over the *k* and the *a* yells its name "eh" instead of its sound "ah". For a word like "little" there are a bunch of consonants there so the *e* can't jump and make the *i* say "I".

I know about "whole word" vs "phonics" is an ongoing debate but is the jumping letter concept a phonics thing? Or did I just have a creative teacher?

Comment: I, for one, have never heard of "jumping letters". However, your teacher's explanation was otherwise valid and important.

Comment: Haha that is pretty sweet. Never heard of it, but I see it works!

Comment: My teacher used a very similar concept :) I think it's a great way to teach pronunciation :)

Comment: @JSBangs: in Russia, teachers use the terms "open syllable" and "closed syllable", but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: @Cerberus “I see it works” – really? How about the word “whole” (which, after all, appears in this very question). (EDIT: I take that back … “whole” *is* kind of pronounced /ho-el/ …).

Comment: Think the open/closed syllable thing could be confusing unless explained in quite a specific way (in "make" and "making", the 'a' is in a closed vs open syllable respectively, but its quality doesn't change; in 'sit' ~ 'site', both are closed syllables but the 'i' vowel changes). Plus I suppose the idea is not to have to teach the concpt of "closed syllable" to 4-year-olds.

Comment: @Neil: why not? I was taught [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) in fourth grade. I could read /ˌʌndɪˈstɪŋɡwɪʃəb(ə)l/ before I could read *undistinguishable*, and I will be eternally thankful for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was just learning to read, my teacher had a sock puppet named Mr. Easy, whose face was a lower-case e with a dot in the enclosure to form his "eye". Mr. Easy's job was to help the vowels say their name. He would tack himself on to **mat** and call out to the vowel: "Tell me your name!" And we, being 5 or 6 and eager to help the vowel, would call out "*A*. Your name is *A*!" And Mr. Easy would then turn to us and ask us what word the *a* was trying to make. And we would shout the answer, laughing and having a great time. And thus *mat* became *mate*, *them* would become *theme*, *bit* would become *bite*, and to this day I remember Mr. Easy.

This is not intended as a glowing little remembrance, but to point out that whatever device a teacher uses to bring an idea to life is a good idea. Kids like games, they like fun, they like cartoonish characters, and they actually love solving problems. Whether the teacher uses a sock puppet or a jumping game, the important thing is that good teaching involves engaging children in a way that makes a lesson fun and memorable.

Comment: Think we had a song called "magic e". I suppose these days, they might not pick that...

Comment: Wow! That's way more impressive than my jumping letters. And good to know it was a creative teacher that made an impact.

Answer (score 1):

I am a tutor, and have great success in using a game, Ring Around the Phonics, to teach phonics and reading.  I think getting into the rules of phonics (except for e at the end of a word) is a bit much until they are reading well.